# Retrieve Active Directory Groups using OneLogin API

Tags: onelogin

Is there a way to retrieve a full list of Active Directory groups using the OneLogin API? the /roles and /groups API calls do not return a full list.

When retrieving User details, there is an array for "member_of" that contains the full list of Active Directory groups a specific User is a part of, however, I do not see a way to bring back the full list of Active Directory groups that are available overall.

Thx!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the relevant code so that it's easier for people to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Because AD can contain literally thousands of groups, OneLogin doesn't compile an internal list of these groups for surfacing via the APIs.

Instead, you can use the user mappings to assign users in selected AD groups to roles in OneLogin and then access that information via the API.

What's your use case?

Comment: So, I am currently using the OneLogin API to authenticate my users and retrieve the AD groups that my authenticated user is a member of. That's all working fine.

However, we now want to add some authorization flows into the app and allow admins to specify access for specific groups. But to do this, I want to bring back a list of Groups that are available. So this flow has no linkage to a specific User, but rather I just want to get all available AD Groups that exist.

Comment: Basically, you want to discover all the possible group values from AD? I'm afraid there are no APIs in onelogin for that sort of query. Only the ability to map certain AD groups to roles in OneLogin and then retrieve those.